# Why "unused attribute" generated warning for array of struct?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, struct, unused-variables

Here used, `unused` attribute with structure.

According to [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) document:

> **unused :**
>
> This attribute, attached to a variable, means that the variable is
>   meant to be possibly unused. GCC will not produce a warning for this
>   variable.

But, In the following code, array of struct generated warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct __attribute__ ((unused)) St 
{ 
    int x; 
};

void func1()
{
  struct St s;      // no warning, ok
}

void func2()
{ 
  struct St s[1];   // Why warning???
}

int main() {
    func1();
    func2();
    return 0;
}
```

Why does GCC generated warning for array of struct?

Comment: Put this attribute to the variable, not to the struct definition. `__attribute__ ((unused)) struct  St s[1];`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not attaching the attribute to a variable, you are attaching it to a type. In this case, different rules apply:

> When attached to a type (including a `union` or a `struct`), this [unused] attribute means that variables of that type are meant to appear possibly unused. GCC will not produce a warning for any variables of that type, even if the variable appears to do nothing.

This is exactly what happens inside `func1`: variable `struct St s` is of type `struct St`, so the warning is not generated.

However, `func2` is different, because the type of `St s[1]` is not `struct St`, but an array of `struct St`. This array type has no special attributes attached to it, hence the warning is generated.

You can add an attribute to an array type of a specific size with `typedef`:

```
typedef __attribute__ ((unused)) struct St ArrayOneSt[1];
...
void func2() { 
  ArrayOneSt s;   // No warning
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/pps5uI)

Comment: I do not recommend hiding array types behind `typedef`. It's easier to make mistakes due to array decay. Array variables (like pointers too) are better declared explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

This attribute should be applied on a variable **not** `struct` definition.
Changing it to

```
void func2()
{ 
  __attribute__ ((unused)) struct St s[1];  
}
```

will do the job.